# regex class for Alpha numericals only?

Tags: sql, regex

'\w' can be used in place of [a-zA_Z0-9_]. I do not need "_" underscore. what is class for alphabets and numericals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none.  Use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: I am using (.*[^(\d)]|^)servername([^(\d)].*|$) as my regex to match the ip addresses/hostnamespresent in text or URL. Do want to eliminate "_" underscore also. testcase-- text c_abcd should match with abcd.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses inside character classes and if I understand you correctly, you want ``[^\d_]``.

Comment: Sorry the regex is (.*[^(\w)]|^)servername([^(\w)].*|$). :)

Comment: What is your question?  As answered above, if you don't want underscores, replace ``[^(\w)]`` with ``[a-zA-Z0-9]``.

Answer (score 2):

use regex `[\da-z]` with regex option `ignoreCase`

Comment: I am using (.*[^(\w)]|^)servername([^(\w)].*|$) as my regex to match the ip addresses/hostnamespresent in text or URL. Do want to eliminate "_" underscore also. testcase-- text c_abcd should match with abcd.